# Can't run sql script

Tags: sql

I can't run this SQL script.

This errors occurs:

> Message 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near the construction "=".
>   Message 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
>   Incorrect syntax near the construction of "`".
>
>   Message 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 56
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the construction of "` ".
>   Message 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 86
>   Incorrect syntax near the construction of "` ".

What can I do?

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.3.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Хост: localhost
-- Время создания: Дек 29 2011 г., 16:23
-- Версия сервера: 5.5.10
-- Версия PHP: 5.2.4

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- База данных: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `customers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'идентификатор записи',
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Имя',
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Фамилия',
  `PHONE` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Телефон',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='заказчики' AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `customers`
--

INSERT INTO `customers` (`ID`, `FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, `PHONE`) VALUES
(1, 'Борис', 'Петров', ''),
(2, 'Иван', 'Сидоров', ''),
(3, 'Сергей', 'Иванов', ''),
(4, 'Александр', 'Бойко', ''),
(5, 'Петр', 'Борисов', ''),
(6, 'Семён', 'Александров', ''),
(7, 'Александр', 'Лебедев', ''),
(8, 'Алексей', 'Ильин', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `items`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'идентификатор записи',
  `NAME` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'название товара',
  `AMOUNT` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'цена товара',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `items`
--

INSERT INTO `items` (`ID`, `NAME`, `AMOUNT`) VALUES
(1, 'Молоток', 0),
(2, 'Бумага', 0),
(3, 'Шоколадка Snickers', 0),
(4, 'Отвёртка', 0),
(5, 'Ручка', 0),
(6, 'Шоколадка Kit-Kat', 0),
(7, 'Гаечный ключ', 0),
(8, 'Карандаш', 0),
(9, 'Конфеты Helth Bar', 0),
(10, 'Счётчик ленты', 0),
(11, 'Переплётная машина', 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `payments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payments` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'идентификатор записи',
  `CUSTOMER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ИД заказчика. Связь с таблицей customers',
  `ITEM_ID` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ИД товара. Связь с таблицей items',
  `ITEM_COUNT` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'количество товара',
  `TRANS_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'время транзакции',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='продажи' AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `payments`
--

INSERT INTO `payments` (`ID`, `CUSTOMER_ID`, `ITEM_ID`, `ITEM_COUNT`, `TRANS_TIME`) VALUES
(1, 1, 6, 0, '2011-12-29 14:49:06'),
(2, 1, 9, 0, '2011-12-29 14:49:06'),
(3, 2, 2, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:09'),
(4, 2, 8, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:09'),
(5, 3, 4, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:09'),
(6, 3, 7, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:09'),
(7, 3, 10, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:09'),
(8, 4, 5, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:09'),
(9, 4, 8, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:09'),
(10, 4, 11, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:09'),
(11, 5, 1, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:09'),
(12, 5, 4, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:09'),
(13, 5, 10, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:35'),
(14, 6, 5, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:35'),
(15, 6, 11, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:55'),
(16, 7, 1, 0, '2011-12-29 14:52:55'),
(17, 7, 4, 0, '2011-12-29 14:53:12'),
(18, 8, 3, 0, '2011-12-29 14:53:12'),
(19, 8, 9, 0, '2011-12-29 14:53:22'),
(20, 2, 11, 0, '2011-12-29 16:03:55');
```

Comment: Post the SQL which generates these errors.  You likely have syntax wrong somehwere.

Comment: Adding a whole zip file instead of properly phrasing your question is just lazy.

Comment: Please, download file and try to run it. Sql script is too long to post it here, it would take a lot of place.

Comment: Try running each section of the script one by one instead of the entire thing. That will help with narrowing down which part is breaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run a MySQL script on a SQL Server database. You will need to make many changes before that works. Try this (I have ported your code to TSQL):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #AddDescription
    (@table sysname, @column sysname, @description sysname)
AS
    DECLARE @level2type sysname;

    IF @column COLLATE database_default IS NOT NULL
        SET @level2type = 'COLUMN'

    EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty
        'MS_Description', @description,
        'SCHEMA', 'dbo',
        'TABLE', @table,
        @level2type, @column
GO

IF 'customers' NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [customers]
    (
        [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(9,1),
        [FIRST_NAME] nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
        [LAST_NAME] nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
        [PHONE] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
    )

    EXEC #AddDescription 'customers', NULL, N'заказчики'
    EXEC #AddDescription 'customers', 'ID', N'идентификатор записи'
    EXEC #AddDescription 'customers', 'FIRST_NAME', N'Имя'
    EXEC #AddDescription 'customers', 'LAST_NAME', N'Фамилия'
    EXEC #AddDescription 'customers', 'PHONE', N'Телефон'
END

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [customers] ON

INSERT INTO [customers] ([ID], [FIRST_NAME], [LAST_NAME], [PHONE]) SELECT
1, N'Борис', N'Петров', '' UNION ALL SELECT
2, N'Иван', N'Сидоров', '' UNION ALL SELECT
3, N'Сергей', N'Иванов', '' UNION ALL SELECT
4, N'Александр', N'Бойко', '' UNION ALL SELECT
5, N'Петр', N'Борисов', '' UNION ALL SELECT
6, N'Семён', N'Александров', '' UNION ALL SELECT
7, N'Александр', N'Лебедев', '' UNION ALL SELECT
8, N'Алексей', N'Ильин', '';

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [customers] OFF

DBCC CHECKIDENT('[customers]', RESEED) WITH NO_INFOMSGS 

IF 'items' NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [items]
    (
        [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(12,1),
        [NAME] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
        [AMOUNT] float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
    )

    EXEC #AddDescription 'items', 'ID', N'идентификатор записи'
    EXEC #AddDescription 'items', 'NAME', N'название товара'
    EXEC #AddDescription 'items', 'AMOUNT', N'цена товара'
END

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [items] ON

INSERT INTO [items] ([ID], [NAME], [AMOUNT]) SELECT
1, N'Молоток', 0 UNION ALL SELECT
2, N'Бумага', 0 UNION ALL SELECT
3, N'Шоколадка Snickers', 0 UNION ALL SELECT
4, N'Отвёртка', 0 UNION ALL SELECT
5, N'Ручка', 0 UNION ALL SELECT
6, N'Шоколадка Kit-Kat', 0 UNION ALL SELECT
7, N'Гаечный ключ', 0 UNION ALL SELECT
8, N'Карандаш', 0 UNION ALL SELECT
9, N'Конфеты Helth Bar', 0 UNION ALL SELECT
10, N'Счётчик ленты', 0 UNION ALL SELECT
11, N'Переплётная машина', 0;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [items] OFF

DBCC CHECKIDENT('items', RESEED) WITH NO_INFOMSGS 

IF 'payments' NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [payments]
    (
        [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(21,1),
        [CUSTOMER_ID] int NOT NULL,
        [ITEM_ID] int NOT NULL ,
        [ITEM_COUNT] int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        [TRANS_TIME] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
    )

    EXEC #AddDescription 'payments', NULL, N'продажи' 
    EXEC #AddDescription 'payments', 'ID', N'идентификатор записи'
    EXEC #AddDescription
        'payments', 'CUSTOMER_ID', N'ИД заказчика. Связь с таблицей customers'
    EXEC #AddDescription
        'payments', 'ITEM_ID', N'ИД товара. Связь с таблицей items'
    EXEC #AddDescription 'payments', 'ITEM_COUNT', N'количество товар'
    EXEC #AddDescription 'payments', 'TRANS_TIME', N'время транзакции'
END

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [payments] ON

INSERT INTO [payments]
([ID], [CUSTOMER_ID], [ITEM_ID], [ITEM_COUNT], [TRANS_TIME]) SELECT
1, 1, 6, 0, '2011-12-29T14:49:06' UNION ALL SELECT
2, 1, 9, 0, '2011-12-29T14:49:06' UNION ALL SELECT
3, 2, 2, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:09' UNION ALL SELECT
4, 2, 8, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:09' UNION ALL SELECT
5, 3, 4, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:09' UNION ALL SELECT
6, 3, 7, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:09' UNION ALL SELECT
7, 3, 10, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:09' UNION ALL SELECT
8, 4, 5, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:09' UNION ALL SELECT
9, 4, 8, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:09' UNION ALL SELECT
10, 4, 11, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:09' UNION ALL SELECT
11, 5, 1, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:09' UNION ALL SELECT
12, 5, 4, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:09' UNION ALL SELECT
13, 5, 10, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:35' UNION ALL SELECT
14, 6, 5, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:35' UNION ALL SELECT
15, 6, 11, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:55' UNION ALL SELECT
16, 7, 1, 0, '2011-12-29T14:52:55' UNION ALL SELECT
17, 7, 4, 0, '2011-12-29T14:53:12' UNION ALL SELECT
18, 8, 3, 0, '2011-12-29T14:53:12' UNION ALL SELECT
19, 8, 9, 0, '2011-12-29T14:53:22' UNION ALL SELECT
20, 2, 11, 0, '2011-12-29T16:03:55'

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [payments] OFF

DBCC CHECKIDENT('payments', RESEED) WITH NO_INFOMSGS 

DROP PROCEDURE #AddDescription
```